# JQuery blockUI plugin and JQuery Tools overlay feature not working together

Tags: jquery, jquery-tools, jquery-blockui

I am using jquery.BlockUI to block a page when performing ajax call to a back end script. It was working fine, but once I had added jquery.overlay from jquery TOOLS, blockUI plugin stopped working. 
So if I remove

```
<script src="js/jquery.tools.min.js"></script>
```

line then blockUI is working fine.
Could you please advise me on how I can force these two things work together

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Without a link to your project it is hard to tell, but it is likely that the version of jqueryTools you are adding might also include an additional version of jQuery which could be causing the conflict with another version of jQuery that is also being loaded on your page.

You can download different versions of jQueryTools with or without jQuery included.